# How do I pixelate/blur detected face in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

I need to automate blurring/pixelation of faces in a video. I did this using a MATLAB script. I have the R2013a version, so functions like readFrame and hasFrame don't work, hence the weird code. The code currently annotates the face using a box. I need to pixelate this area, or preferably use gaussian blur over this. How do I do it? I am not able to find anything relevant.

```
%%MATLAB Code for R2013a (Code needs revision for newer versions) for boxing faces in a mp4 file file.mp4, saving it in AVI format as Detected_One
videoFReader = vision.VideoFileReader('file.mp4');
Videra=VideoReader('file.mp4');
%%Extracts original footage's num_frames and frame_rate
numFr=Videra.NumberOfFrames;
frmRa=Videra.FrameRate;
writerObj = VideoWriter('Detected_One');
%%Sets the written video's framerate as that of old
writerObj.FrameRate = frmRa;
open(writerObj);
faceDetector = vision.CascadeObjectDetector();

for i=1:numFr
    display(i);
    videoFrame = step(videoFReader);
    bbox            = step(faceDetector, videoFrame);
    videoOut = insertObjectAnnotation(videoFrame,'rectangle',bbox,'Face');
    writeVideo(writerObj,videoOut);
close(figure);

end

release(videoFReader);
close(writerObj);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you google "gaussian blur Matlab" you'll get to the next page:

http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/fspecial.html

where you can understand how to blur:

```
H = fspecial('gaussian',[5 5],0.5);
blurred = imfilter(Image,H,'replicate');
```

If you just want to blur a part of the image, extract that part, blur it and then patch it again!

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about possibility of extracting and patching parts of image.

Comment: @Ashtrix no prob ;). Hope the answer helps.

Comment: I have got this working with the extracted part blurred, but I don't know how to patch it back. What is the easiest way to patch this extracted part back to where it belonged?

Comment: If you have a mask of which parts are the extracted, it would be something like `FullImage(mask)=Blurred`